# Find average of several cells then autofill

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am looking to find the average of cells A2:D2 and place them into E2 then auto fill that equation into the rest of the 500 or so E cells. Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub average ()
Dim nRows As Integer
Dim nCols As Integer

nCols = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
nRows = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[]C[ " & nCols & "]:R[]C[])"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Macro below will put the average of A to D in column E for each row and pull the formula down to the last row of your worksheet.

```
Sub Average()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim ACell As String
Dim Col As String

    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-4]:RC[-1])"
    lRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row, 
    Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row, Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row)
    ACell = Range("E2").Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
    Col = Left(ACell, 1)
    Range(ACell & ":" & ACell).AutoFill Range(ACell & ":" & Col & lRow)
```

End Sub